# How does Wagtail approach structural content?

Tags: wagtail

I am using Wagtail 1.0. I have several kinds (about 8) of pages (Homepage, Contact Page, About our Team page..., News Page and so on).

Let us take About Our Team page as an example. In the middle of the page (in PSD design), we have blocks of team members. Above that is general contact information block, after that is more detailed information block.

Now, I consider the middle block a kind of structural content. Each block has member full name, image, contact address, twitter handle and so on.

I would use InlinePanel, clustermodel... but that would mean I have to create an entire table for the Contact Page and a Contact model. However, would someone use an entire table just to persist one row!!
**What is the standard way to approach this section of data the Wagtail way?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, creating a new table for this would be the recommended Wagtail approach. Django makes defining new tables easy and 'cheap' - there's no reason to avoid it simply because they won't contain much data.

As an alternative, you could look at StreamField: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0/topics/streamfield.html.

Comment: I would definitely go for the StreamField option. Do you know how to make block content searchable?

Comment: If you're using ElasticSearch, just add it to your model's `search_fields`, as described in http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-extra-fields - StreamField content will get indexed just like any other field.